# Energy gained from eating a bagel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work, biophysics, estimation

I have done some quick back of the envelope calculations to determine the amount of exercise one would need to do to burn off the energy consumed by eating a bagel. The result appears to be unreasonably low so I was wondering where I made a mistake.

First a bagel has about 250 calories in it
there are about 4 joules in a calorie there for a bagel has 1000 joules
Lifting a milk jug requires about 40 N of force (10m/s^2 * 4kg)
to use 1000 joules one would need to lift a milk jug 1000/40 = 25 meters
This could be done more easily by lifting it 0.5m (about the distance from wait to shoulder) 50 times

From this I conclude that lifting a jug of milk 50 times would burn the amount of energy contained in a bagel. Is this reasonable?

I'd also like to point out that this is assuming a human is 100% efficient. Obviously this is not the case so it should take less than 50 lifts to burn a bagel.

An even better comparison, the energy needed to walk up a flight of stairs: about 3m. say a person weighs 70kg then that is 70kg*10m/s^2*3m = 2100J. About two bagels worth of energy.

Comment: Food calories are normally actually kilocalories = 4200 joules

Comment: So when something say "x amount of calories" its actually measuring in kilocalories?

Comment: Yep, look at the (small) k in front of cal on the food wrappers. but joules is better for estimations in physics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's physics content is minimal, it is mostly biology, imo

Comment: I would argue that it's actually the biology content is minimal. It's a not particularly deep physics question, but if we replaced the word bagel with 'a source of energy' and human with 'heat engine' then it would not be a biology question at all, just a simple high school physics problem.

Comment: The physics of calories is case-sensitive: 1 Calorie is 1000 calories.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is effectively a duplicate of [Climbing Stairs and Calories Burnt](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/248730/climbing-stairs-and-calories-burnt).

Answer (score 1):

This is really a BiologySE question, but there is a small bit of physics in it.

A simple rule of thumb is 100 calories per mile for a 180 pound person. You can use some kcal up converting that to proper units (SI units) :)

Source: [Food into Energy](https://www.quora.com/How-efficient-is-the-human-body-at-converting-matter-food-into-energy)

> First, technically, the human body doesn't convert matter into energy, it just extracts chemical energy from the food.  The actual matter is either absorbed into the body (like proteins) or is discarded in the form of either moisture or waste.

[image]

This is how food energy is apportioned in the human body.

> Studies on athletic motion suggest that the human body can turn about 20% of the food energy it absorbs into actual mechanical energy (like turning a generator or lifting objects).  The rest goes into the normal energy of body processes, or is lost to inefficiency.  The thing is, like any energy user, all of the energy that's lost ends up as waste heat.  That means that, if you don't produce any other form of energy, then all the calories you burn end up as body heat.